# Improving "anybody to invite"

Tags: exam-questions

> I can't think of **anybody whom to invite**.
>
> 1. Anybody whom I should invite
> 2. Anybody to invite
> 3. Anybody who should be invited
> 4. No improvement.

This is my exam question and provisional answer key suggested option 3. But I can't understand why other options are incorrect.

Comment: This is an exam question from what source?  Multiple answers are possible, yet all are ugly.  If the book considers this a good test of English skill then it's not very reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I think both #2 and #3 sound fine, but it's worth noting that they don't necessarily mean quite exactly the same thing.

> I can't think of anybody to invite.

This could mean you are trying to think of someone to invite, but you can't think of anyone. Your mind is blank. I would say this if I was trying to think of people to invite, but no names came to mind.

> I can't think of anybody who should be invited.

This is slightly different, because of the phrase *should be*. Who should be invited? People who will make the event better, people who aren't nursing a grudge against the family, etc. I would use this when I was trying to think of people to invite, but, out of all the people I considered, no one seemed like a good fit for the event.

It's also worth noting that, even though they ***can*** mean something different, they can also be used somewhat interchangeably. Let's say you ask me, "Who should we invite to the party?" Mentally, I think to myself:

- *Not Bob; he doesn't get along with Mary.*
- *Not Leslie; she has been mad at me for ten years.*
- *Not Alex; Alex lives too far away.*

At this point, a valid response back to you could be:

> I can't think of anybody to invite.

Therefore, I'm in agreement with Andrew's initial comment – it's not readily clear why one of these would be considered an "improvement" more so than the other.